# Custom expression in Icon Settings based on two other columns

Tags: analytics, business-intelligence, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I have created a graphical table in spotfire

I have columns 'Group', 'Score', 'Pass/Fail'

I want to setup Alert Icon(Pass/Fail column) red or green circle base on Score. But pass-fail criteria is different for different groups. let say for group1 is 35% and group2 is 40%

How can I write a customer expression for this?

I cannot see the Group or Score as column to select in the "Customer Expression" window. I see only Axis.Icon in the 'Column' section

I was thinking of using something like this below in the icon setting custom expression

```
case 
WHEN [Group] = 'Group1' and [Score] < 35 THEN Axis.Icon = 'Square' and Axis.Icon.Color = 'Red'

WHEN [Group] = 'Group2' and [Score] < 40 THEN Axis.Icon = 'Square' and Axis.Icon.Color = 'Red'

END
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So that is not possible with Spotfire Icon settings to use multiple column. The workaround is that

1. I create a calculated column 'PW' in the data table having alphabetic value representation of conditional pass/fail based on group and score. i.e. p for pass and f for fail
2. I went to graphical table - icon setting for 'Pass/Fail' column, selected newly created column i.e First(PW) and then added new rule for pass and fail using 'start with' condition on to display a green or fail colored icons